# Can I charge multiple identical devices in parallel from on transformer

Tags: transformer, charger, parallel

I have four identical devices (HDD enclosures), each requiring 12V, 2000mA. Each of them came with their own power supply/DC transformer, but they are fat and chunky, and if possible I'd like to recover some sockets space on my multi-socket adaptor.

I had though to take one of the power supply unit, and simply splice on the end of the other three units on to the output wire, forming a 4 piece y-cable of sorts.

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/60783/29066) to another similar question seems to indicate so, but will the transformer be able to supply enough current to the enclosures in parallel?

Comment: Why would a manufacturer of a power supply design it so that it can provide 4 times the power just in case someone wanted to splice 3 more devices onto it? Same with cars - mine's got about 100 horsepower and I wouldn't expect it to pull three 1 tonne trailers.

Comment: The cable might also not be able to withstand 4x the current, even if the power supply could deliver 4x the current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a single power supply designed for 12V 2A will not supply 12V 8A, and when asked to do so will likely shutdown or fail in some other way; low voltage, overheat, blow internal fuse.

The time this will happen is when it is most inconvenient; several minutes after some of the drives have spun up and have begun to write data.  Your data may not survive the experience.  That includes data already safely written.

You need a 12V 8A power supply to do this.

You also need to worry about the effects of the disk on the power supply, affecting the next disk.

Comment: Thank you @James Cameron; If I were to get a 12V power supply with extra current, say 10A, and splice that, would that mitigate power effects between drives? I assume that the problem would be dips in current during spin up or similar.

Comment: Maybe.  You would have to test.  You probably don't have the full specification of the power supply or the disk; you are focusing on the rating only, which is on the label because of regulation.  The other specifications might include voltage static regulation, current range, ripple and noise, turn on delay or rise time, and dynamic load change response.  Since you are designing without these specifications, you would have to test statistically.  Test at least a hundred disks, so that you can get a statistical sample, at varying temperature ranges over many hours.  Then you can know.

Comment: I ended up taking the enclosures and plugs into a local electronics store to ask if they had a transformer capable of powering the lot. The smallest 10A transformer they had was larger than all four of the supplied ones put together and cost an unholy fortune to boot. So practically speaking, no I can't save space with a larger transformer

Comment: Yes, that is likely.  While manufacturing cost relates to the power rating of the supply, retail pricing depends on economies of scale; the demand for a 10A 12V supply as a retrofit is much lower than the demand for a 2A 12V supply associated with an external disk enclosure.  I have solved your original problem (no space on multi-socket adapter) by buying an adapter with wider spaced sockets, or more sockets, or replacing the power supplies individually with ones that are thinner.